# two inner join query not run?

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I want to use inner in two tables.
my tables is `users` and `relations` and `users` (again). i want to join `relations` with `users` on `sender_id` and to join again with `reveiver_id`.
my sample code is:

```
select * from 
(relations inner join users on relations.sender_id = users.userid) 
inner join users on relations.reciever_id = users.userid
```

but this code not running. why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM `relations` AS r INNER JOIN 
`users` AS u1 on r.`sender_id` = u1.`userid` INNER JOIN 
`users` AS u2 on r.`reciever_id` = u2.`userid`
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use subquery, then you can use this query -

```
SELECT * FROM 
  (SELECT * FROM `relations`
   INNER JOIN `users`
     ON `relations`.`sender_id` = `users`.`userid`) t
INNER JOIN `users`
  ON t.`reciever_id` = `users`.`userid`
```

But it is the same as -

```
SELECT * FROM `relations`
INNER JOIN `users`
  ON `relations`.`sender_id` = `users`.`userid`
INNER JOIN `users`
  ON `relations`.`reciever_id` = `users`.`userid`
```